# Class Error C2146 syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pTrigger'

Tags: c++, class

I have just started to learn more on classes but now im facing a problem what doesnt make anysense to me.

The error is in "Needed.H" but i added also the code of Trigger.h and Trigger.cpp

"Error C2146 syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pTrigger'"

> Needed.H

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning(disable: 4430)
#include "PMemory.h"
#include "Trigger.h"


ProcMem Mem;

cTrigger pTrigger;

const DWORD playerBase = 0x00A33504;
const DWORD entityBase = 0x04A4EC44;
const DWORD crosshairOffset = 0x0000AA44;

const DWORD teamOffset = 0xF0;
const DWORD healthOffset = 0xFC;
const DWORD EntLoopDist = 0x10;

DWORD triggerKey = 0x05;
```

> Trigger.H

```
#pragma once
#include "needed.h"

class cTrigger
{
public:
    cTrigger();
    ~cTrigger();

    void Trigger();

};
```

> Trigger.cpp

```
#include "Trigger.h"


cTrigger::cTrigger()
{

}

cTrigger::~cTrigger()
{

}

void cTrigger::Trigger()
{

    DWORD ClientDLL = Mem.Module("client.dll");
    DWORD LocalPlayer = Mem.Read<DWORD>(ClientDLL + playerBase);
    int LocalTeam = Mem.Read<int>(LocalPlayer + teamOffset);
    int CrossHairID = Mem.Read<int>(LocalPlayer + crosshairOffset);

    DWORD EnemyInCH = Mem.Read<DWORD>(ClientDLL + entityBase + ((CrossHairID - 1) * EntLoopDist));
    int EnemyHealth = Mem.Read<int>(EnemyInCH + healthOffset);
    int EnemyTeam = Mem.Read<int>(EnemyInCH + teamOffset);

    if (LocalTeam != EnemyTeam && CrossHairID > 0 && EnemyHealth > 0 && GetAsyncKeyState(triggerKey) & 0x8000)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        Sleep(20);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        Sleep(20);
    }
    Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: You have a circular dependency where needed.h depends on trigger.h and vice versa.

Comment: `Triger.h` doesn't need `needed.h`, include `needed.h` only in `Triger.cpp`